# Can pandas df have cell values of numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to store Numpy arrays as values for cells in my Dataframe. Is there any way to do this?
Basically i have pixel data which is a (512,512) Numpy array that i want to save as the value for pixel_data column corresponding to its particular id in the ID column of my Dataframe. How can i do this?

Heres what i tried:

```
for f in train_files[:10]:
    id_tmp = f.split('/')[4].split('.')[0]
    first_dcm = pydicom.read_file(f)
    img = first_dcm.pixel_array
    window = get_windowing(first_dcm)
    image = window_image(img, *window)
    train.loc[train.Image == id_tmp, 'img_before_w'] = img
    train.loc[train.Image == id_tmp, 'img_after_w'] = image
```

The error i got:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-32236f8c9ccc> in <module>
      5     window = get_windowing(first_dcm)
      6     image = window_image(img, *window)
----> 7     train.loc[train.Image == id_tmp, 'img_before_w'] = img
      8     train.loc[train.Image == id_tmp, 'img_after_w'] = image
      9 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    203             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    204         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 205         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    206 
    207     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    525                     if len(labels) != value.shape[1]:
    526                         raise ValueError(
--> 527                             "Must have equal len keys and value "
    528                             "when setting with an ndarray"
    529                         )

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking sample dataframe as below:

```
train=pd.DataFrame({'Image':[1,2,3,2],'img_before_w':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan]})
```

`print(train)` gives

```
   Image  img_before_w
0      1           NaN
1      2           NaN
2      3           NaN
3      2           NaN
```

Now, for example, if you want to insert pixel data when `train.Image == 2`, then it can be achieved using below code:

```
mask = train.Image == 2 # contains True for desired rows
target_index=mask[mask==True].index # gives index of rows, wherever condition is met
train.loc[mask, 'img_before_w'] = pd.Series([[512,512]]*len(target_index), index=target_index)  # inserts [512,512] array in rows wherever condition is met, in given column
```

Now, `print(train)` gives, desired output:

```
Image img_before_w
0      1          NaN
1      2   [512, 512]
2      3          NaN
3      2   [512, 512]
```

Comment: can u explain what you are doing? i'm not sure i understand.

but just to avoid confusion, what i want to do is insert a (512,512) np array corresponding to the value of train_df (id, img)

Comment: @AkashShastri Updated answer with some sample data. Let me know if this works or not.